# How do configure the path where Wildfly 14 modules are installed and located?

Tags: wildfly

I am running several `Wildfly-14` standalone instances on a host, sharing the same `$JBOSS_HOME` and I want each instance to have its own module path.

I have a `jboss-cli` script installing the `oracle jdbc driver`:

```
module add --name=com.oracle.ojdbc8 --resources=/tmp/ojdbc8.jar --dependencies=javax.api,javax.transaction.api,javax.resource.api
```

The oracle module gets installed under `$JBOSS_HOME/modules`, but I want it to be installed under `/jboss/server/modules`. The environment variable `$JBOSS_MODULEPATH` have no effect.

I have set the environment:

`JBOSS_HOME=/opt/wildfly14`

`JBOSS_MODULEPATH=/jboss/server/modules:/opt/wildfly14/modules`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify the module root dir:

```
module add --module-root-dir=/jboss/server/modules --name=com.oracle.ojdbc8 ...
```

Comment: JBOSS_MODULEPATH is still used in Wildfly14 to locate modules.  It was the "module add" that stopped using JBOSS_MODULEPATH and instead got the new parameter "--module-root-dir.